# Using trailing closure in for-in loop

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using `map()` function of array in for-in loop like this:

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

for doubled in numbers.map { $0 * 2 } // compile error
{
    print(doubled)
}
```

which produces compile error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'doubled'

However, if I put parenthesis for `map()` function, it works fine. i.e.

```
for doubled in numbers.map ({ $0 * 2 })
{
    print(doubled)
}
```

My question is, why wouldn't compiler differentiate code block of trailing function and loop, assuming this is causing the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because there would be ambiguity as to the context in which the trailing function should operate. An alternative syntax which works is:

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

for doubled in (numbers.map { $0 * 2 }) // All good :)
{
    print(doubled)
}
```

I would say this is likely because the 'in' operator has a higher precedence than trailing functions.

It's up to you which you think is more readable.

Answer (score 8):

Trailing closure grammar generates a known ambiguity between a body of the statement (in your case, that's `for` loop, but it applies to other statements as well) and the body of trailing closure. Although it is technically possible to solve this problem, [compiler designers decided to prohibit trailing closure syntax in controlling portions of various high-level statements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0056-trailing-closures-in-guard.md):

> While it would be possible to tell what is intended in some cases by performing arbitrary lookahead or by performing type checking while parsing, these approaches have significant consequences for the architecture for the compiler. As such, we've opted keep the parser simple and disallow this.

To understand the nature of the conflict, consider this example:

```
for v in expr { /* code 1 */ } { /* code 2 */ }
```

The parser needs to make a choice regarding `code 1` block. It could either use it as a trailing closure of `expr` and treat `code 2` as the body of the `for` loop, or use `code 1` as the body of the `for` loop, while treating `code 2` as an independent group of statements enclosed in curly braces - a classic [*shift-reduce conflict*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Conflicts_in_the_constructed_tables).

Solving such conflicts is very expensive. Essentially, your parser needs to continue looking ahead through more tokens, until only one interpretation makes sense, or the parser runs out of tokens (in which case it makes an arbitrary decision one way or the other, requiring the programmers to disambiguate their program when that choice is not what they wanted).

Adding parentheses removes the ambiguity. Proposals were considered to remove the ambiguity by adding a mandatory keyword to separate the control portion of the loop from its body, i.e.

```
// The syntax of rejected proposal
for doubled in numbers.map { $0 * 2 } do {
    print(doubled) //                 ^^
}
```

Adding an extra `do` keyword "attaches" the block on the left, if any, to the expression, and makes the block on the right the body of the loop statement. This approach has a major drawback, because it is a breaking change. That is why this proposal has been rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @M.Hassan You are welcome! I figured that since you already have a nice work-around, I should concentrate on the nature of the problem from compiler writer's perspective.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is ambiguous (see [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38375752/669586)). For an alternative syntax:

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

numbers.map { $0 * 2 }.forEach {
    print(doubled)
}
```

or

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
let doubledNumbers = numbers.map { $0 * 2 }

for doubled in doubledNumbers {
    print(doubled)
}
```

Comment: This is not a functional approach. It's just a method. (A functional forEach, if such a thing existed, would return something useful, not rely on a side effect.) I only make the point because I keep seeing `forEach` pop up in places where it is inappropriate (in most cases, `for-in` is the far better Swift), and I suspect "because it's the functional way" is one reason. In this case, at the end of a map/filter chain, it can be useful, but not because it's based on functional programming (it's the opposite); just because the syntax sometimes lines up with map/filter chains a little nicer.

Comment: @RobNapier I do agree that `forEach` is not purely functional (although many programmers call it functional because you can pass a function to it and the word "functional" is not exactly well defined). However, I don't agree than `for-in` is better than `forEach`. How is `for-in` better?

Comment: It honors return/break/continue (the `forEach` treatment of `return` is likely to surprise many devs). It doesn't cause closure capture. It matches the rest of Swift flow-control (if, do, while, repeat). I don't think it's an accident that The Swift Programming Language book explains `map` and `for-in`, but never mentions `forEach`. See also clattner's comments about how "forEach (barely) pays for itself" because you can pass a non-anonymous function to it. https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/003388.html.

Comment: There was a very interesting discussion about removing it (https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001126.html). Most people wanted to keep it, but the commonly cited use was passing named functions, not as a for-in replacement. And there was a lot of discussion about ways to improve it so that it didn't have the problems it currently has (but likely post-Swift 3).

Comment: It's use in `xs?.forEach(doThing)` is also an interesting case, though Chris Lattner recommended `for x in xs ?? []` instead. Others noted that this isn't quite as flexible as the `xs?.forEach` version (if xs is a custom collection), but again, this is always discussed as a corner case, not "you should replace for-in with forEach."

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the information. All of it very interesting. I missed the difference in `continue` and `break` because usually I am solving those use cases by `filter`, `find` or similar functions. Not always it can be so simple though.